# ZipFile.extractall removes files from zip but doesn't save them anywhere

Tags: python, zip, extract, python-zipfile

I'm writing a function which takes a set of files then either:

- saves the files to a zip file if they are present.
- or extract files from said zip file if they are not present.

Saving the files to a zip is working fine, but when it comes to extracting the files from my zip, the zip is emptied but no files are saved to the path that I have pointed extractall to. No errors are raised in the console.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this? I've attempted manually closing the zip file after the `except` clause in case that is causing the first `with` to not unload properly, but that didn't appear to fix anything.

Code:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

files = ['Combine1.docm', 'Combine2.docm', 'Combine3.docm',
        'Combine4.docm', 'Combine5.docm', 'FinalMaster.docm',
        'FinalMasterBeltDrier.docm', 'FinalMasterExport.docm']

backupZip = 'WorkaroundBackup.zip'

def ZipSave(files, backupZip):             
    #backs up files to zip if present, restores from backup zip if not present
    try:
        with ZipFile(backupZip, 'w') as zipWrite:
            for file in files:
                zipWrite.write(file, compress_type=None)
        
        print('Files backed up to %s.' %(backupZip))
        return

    except FileNotFoundError:   #catches files not present case
        with ZipFile(backupZip, 'r') as zipRead:
            zipRead.extractall(path = 'F:\DW Master\Template Docs Workaround')
        
        print('Files not found; restoring from %s.' %(backupZip))
        return
            
ZipSave(files, backupZip)
```